# XSS Vulnerabilities Checkmarx In REST API MultiValueMap

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, checkmarx

Checkmarx is giving XSS vulnerability for following method in my Controller class. Specifically: This element’s value (MultiValueMap<String, String> headers) then flows through the code without being properly sanitized or validated and is eventually displayed to the user in method:

```
 @PutMapping(value = "<URL>{listId}/some/{itemId}", consumes = {APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<String> deleteBlacklistItem(@PathVariable("itemId") String itemId,
                                                      @PathVariable("listId") String listId,
                                                      @RequestHeader MultiValueMap<String, String> headers) {
                                <calling service >                    

    }
```

I tried; I created one customized filter. as below in the security configuration class.

```
public FilterRegistrationBean xssPreventFilter() {
    FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registrationBean.setFilter(new XSSFilter());
    registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
    return registrationBean;
}
```

and

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .headers()
                .xssProtection()
                .and()
                .contentSecurityPolicy("script-src 'self'")
                .and()
                .frameOptions()
                .deny()
                .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/abc/api/*").permitAll();
    }
```

But above solution is not working can some one help me? Not sure, how we can  sanitized or validated Multivaluemap.

Also I implement one coutomized solution as below. But my lead said like they want some solution should be there at spring security level

```
public static MultiValueMap<String, String> sanitizeObject(Object object) throws JSONException, IOException {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = Jsoup.clean(StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(gson.toJson(object)), Whitelist.basic());
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);

        Iterator<String> nameItr = jsonObject.keys();
        Map<String, String> outMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        while(nameItr.hasNext()) {
            String name = nameItr.next();
            outMap.put(name, jsonObject.getString(name));

        }
        MultiValueMap<String, String> multiValueMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>(
                outMap.entrySet().stream().collect(
                        Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> Arrays.asList(e.getValue()))));
        System.out.println(multiValueMap);
        return multiValueMap;
    }
```

//Controller

```
@GetMapping(value = "/<API URL>/filter", consumes = {APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
        public ResponseEntity<String> deletelistItem(@RequestHeader MultiValueMap<String, String> headers,
                                                  @RequestParam Map<String, String> request) throws JSONException, IOException {
           ResponseEntity response = service.getDeleteId(headers, request);
            return response;
        }
```

//Service Class

```
public ResponseEntity getDeleteId(MultiValueMap<String, String> headers, Map<String, String> request) {
            response = clousservice.getDeleteListId(request.get(QUERY_KEY_VALUE), headers);
        }
```

//Cloud Service

```
@Override
    public ResponseEntity<String> getDeleteId(String id, MultiValueMap<String, String> headers) {
            ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(deleteUrl, GET, entity, String.class);
            log.info("Http Response ", response.getStatusCode());
            return response;
        } catch (HttpClientErrorException | HttpServerErrorException e) {
            throw new CustomizeException(e.getResponseBodyAsString(), e, e.getStatusCode());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new CustomizeException("Unable Delete", e, BAD_GATEWAY);
        }
    }
```

Comment: you have excluded the code that tells us what you are actually doing with the map so how can we know?

Comment: From my experience with Checkmarx, it is a static code analysis tool, so adding filters does not actually resolve the findings as it cannot see them at analysis time. I never found any generalized solutions to findings like this. An approach like [this dzone article](https://dzone.com/articles/anti-cross-site-scripting-xss-for-spring-boot-apps) was helpful to me, but required marking findings as false positive after discussing with the info security team.

Comment: Hi @Toerktumlare we received this multivaluemap from component and send same header to cloud to perform the action. so this header will require to get output of end destination.

Comment: Hi @SteveRiesenberg, do you have any link where it mentioned Checkmarx is a static code analysis tool. Because, why I am asking I need to go there and want to know, how checkmarx is working? if you have please let me know.

Comment: your explanation makes no sense, i dont understand.

Comment: @Toerktumlare The controller class receives the header from ESP(component); thereafter controller passes this header to the service class. After that, we have an API service class that we call the cloud service.

Comment: please **dont describe your code, update your question with your code**. I was asking for the CODE, not your intention with the code. remove the `<calling service>` and insert your ACTUAL code

Comment: @Toerktumlare, I update the code.

Comment: You are not even using headers

Comment: Sorry @Java-Singh I don't have much more info than that. Checkmarx was just something I happened to use when the info security team where I worked required us to use it. Based on your description, I assume you're using [this product](https://checkmarx.com/product/cxsast-source-code-scanning/) which is "Source Code Scanning".